# tex4ebook: Numbering in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht, tex4ebook

`tex4ebook` adds an additional numbering in front of each part/chapter/section etc in the table of contents:

```
1. I First Part
   1. 1 First Chapter of Part 1
      1. 1.1 Header of Section 1
      2. 1.2 Header of Section 2
   2. 2 Second Chapter of Part 1
```

Is there a way to prevent the first number to be shown in the ToC so that it looks the same way as if compiling a pdf, i.e.:

```
I First Part
   1 First Chapter of Part 1
      1.1 Header of Section 1
      1.2 Header of Section 2
   2 Second Chapter of Part 1
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Part}

\chapter{First Chapter of part 1}

\section{Header of Section 1} 
Text within section 1.

\section{Header of Section 2} 
Text within section 2.

\chapter{Second Chapter of part 1}

\part{Second Part}
\section{First Chapter of part 2}
Text within part 2.

\end{document}
```

and the config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbering can be removed using this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{nav ol li{
  list-style-type: none;
}}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The CSS rule removes numbering from ordered lists that are contained in the `<nav>` element, which is used for TOC.

This is the result:

[image]